# WSGI ( is caching mysql result until script code is modified ) code included. ( want to stop this caching )

Tags: python, apache, caching, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This is the basic wsgi code.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "root",
                        passwd = "",
                        db = "a")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("select * from `01` where id in (1,2) limit 2")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()

test = rows[0][1]
test2 = rows[1][1]

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield test
```

the problem here is the mysql result is being cached.. it is not mysql caching it.. i suspect it is this script doing it.

i would like a solution to stop this unwanted caching.

currently the only way to clear the caching seems to be to modify the script code above.. as in.. simply updating it seems to do the trick..

but i can not just update it 24/7.. there has to be a way to turn this caching off.

should i add a rand() number to the mysql query.. would that solve the problem ? obviously something is caching the mysql results simply because either

```
a) the mysql query is same as something previously executed
b) the script has not been modified ever since it executed a mysql query ?
```

Comment: Put your query (just query section and not connection to db section) in a function that return the result. then call it within application function.

Comment: i think i need to ensure the wsgi script itself wont cache itself or something...

Comment: The WSGI script file is loaded once per process lifetime and so is used across multiple requests. As already pointed out, execute the actual query on each request to the application and not once at the time the script is loaded as you are doing. If a multithreaded configuration, don't reuse connection ad create a fresh one of those on each request as well, or use database connection pooling.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton is the solution something like adding a random number to the mysql query or is it more like adding something like Content-Type 'no-cache' to the headers of the script ?

Comment: BTW thanks for all the info... at least i am beginning to realize this is about how WSGI runs within single processes while PHP is different.

Answer (score 0):

Anything at module level is executed once, when the script is first run or imported. Your application function always yields the same result, the one that was calculated on first run.

As Omid says in the comments, you need to put the SQL code in a function that is called from the application function.

Comment: that will work ? .. i have been resistant to such solution given that this was never the case when i was working with PHP long time ago. in PHP function or no function did not matter.. code had no reason to be cached unless asked to be cached in some way

Comment: Well, you're writing Python not PHP. In any case, since both I and two commenters - one of whom is *the author of mod_wsgi* - all tell you this is the solution, you should probably accept that it is.