# modwsgi and mysql. queries only show actual result after touched wsgi file

Tags: python, mysql, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

I have a problem with modwsgi and mysql. I have a really simple wsgi application:

```
import MySQLdb
conn_mysql = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'asd', 'testwsgi')

def application(environ, start_response):
    status='200 OK'
    start_response(status, [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    result = getTheResult()
    return result

def getTheResult():
    returnStr = ""
    cursor_mysql = conn_mysql.cursor()
    cursor_mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM test1")

    for row in cursor_mysql:
        returnStr = returnStr + row[1] + " " + row[2] + "<br>"
    cursor_mysql.close()
    return returnStr
```

Whenever I make a change in the mysql database the result won't reflect it until I touch the wsgi file. I run wsgi in daemon mode.

I found this post and I think i do everything which is suggested:

[WSGI ( is caching mysql result until script code is modified ) code included. ( want to stop this caching )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046231/wsgi-is-caching-mysql-result-until-script-code-is-modified-code-included)

I'm sure I must overlook something very easy. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Not likely the reason for your problem, but this code isn't necessarily thread safe to start with and that would be a problem since mod_wsgi daemon mode is multithreaded by default. You should create the connection for each request and not globally once on module import.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GrahamDumpleton. That actually solved my problem. I moved conn_mysql = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'asd', 'testwsgi') into the getTheResult() function. Does this mean if I declare something globally it only gets loaded once? Even for imported modules?

Comment: It only gets executed once if at global scope in module. That will occur at the time the module is imported.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed by moving the connection to the mysql db in the getTheResult() function.

```
import MySQLdb

def application(environ, start_response):
    status='200 OK'
    start_response(status, [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    result = getTheResult()
    return result

def getTheResult():
    conn_mysql = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'asd', 'testwsgi')
    returnStr = ""
    cursor_mysql = conn_mysql.cursor()
    cursor_mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM test1")

    for row in cursor_mysql:
        returnStr = returnStr + row[1] + " " + row[2] + "<br>"
    cursor_mysql.close()
    return returnStr
```